# adb shell cmgs AT command in pdu mode on Redmi 7 not working

Tags: linux, adb, at-command, redmi-device

I run these commands:

```
cat /dev/smd7 & echo "AT+CSCS=\"GSM\";\r" > /dev/smd7
cat /dev/smd7 & echo "AT+CMGF=0;\r" > /dev/smd7
cat /dev/smd7 & echo "AT+CMGS=24;\r" > /dev/smd7
```

Then I enter the PDU message:

```
07...985C369F01
```

I get this output:

```
/system/bin/sh: 07...985C369F01: not found
```

Comment: How do you send the PDU message? By using `echo` command as well?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni No, after the <cat /dev/smd7 & echo "AT+CMGS=24;\r" > /dev/smd7> I get a new line in the prompt with '>', then I write the PDU and hit Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze the two commands you provide to your shell:

```
cat /dev/smd7 &
echo "some_data" > /dev/smd7
```

1. `cat /dev/smd7 &`: Listen to device `/dev/smd7`: from now on all data coming **from** that device will be redirected to the stdout (the shell you are writing in). Do it in background (`&`) in order to be able to send further commands
2. `echo "some_data" > /dev/smd7`: send `some_data` **to** device `/dev/smd7`

   1. The connection with the device is open
   2. The data is sent
   3. The connection is closed **and the control comes back to the shell**

---

When you send `echo "AT+CMGS=24;\r" > /dev/smd7`

1. `AT+CMGS=24;\r` is sent to the device
2. The connection is closed
3. ... in the meanwhile the device sends back `>` prompt character telling you that it is waiting for the PDU message
4. ... but the shell has the control. The `>` prompt is just a print on the shell, so **any sent data will be directly sent to the shell!**
5. Since the sent data is not a shell command, the `not found` error is shown

---

**In conclusion**, in order to send correctly the PDU message to the device, just keep sending it through `echo` command:

```
echo "07...985C369F01" > /dev/smd7
```

**Note:** Make sure to terminate the sequence with CTRL+Z character (ASCII `0x1A`).

Answer (score 0):

```
strace 2>/dev/null -e inject=ioctl:retval=0 microcom /dev/smd7
```

for an interactive session :D